# Big O for a $\cos$ series

Tags: trigonometry, summation, asymptotics

I have to show that $ \sum_1^N \cos(nx) = O(\frac 1{|x|}), [-\pi, \pi] $, x different from 0.

I really don't know how to show that.  I obviously know that $\cos(nx)$ is bounded by $1$, I know what big O means, but I have totally no clue for that one.  Any hint?  Thank you.

Comment: Is the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos(nx)$? That doesn't converge.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem that it doesn't converge

Comment: Oh it's a problem, alright. If something doesn't exist, how can it be $O$ of anything?

Comment: My bad, it's not the sum until infinity but the partial sum

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: You need to find a $k$ such that  $\left|\sum_1^N \cos(nx)\right| \le \frac{k}{|x|} $ for all positive integer $N$ and all $x$ in the range.  My guess is that $k=\pi$ is likely to be enough for large $x$ and more than enough for $x$ close to $0$.

Comment: We can find a formula for the partial sum, using trig identities or complex numbers.

Comment: More about sum, we get something like $2\sin(x/2)$ in the denominator, which gives our $O(1/|x|)$.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos(nx) \right| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N} |cos(nx)| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N} 1 = N = N\pi \frac{1}{\pi} \leq N\pi \frac{1}{|x|}
$$

for $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$, $x \neq 0$.

More generally, since the sum is bounded by the constant $N$ we can deduce that

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos(nx) = O(f(x))
$$

for any function $f$ satisfying $|f(x)| \geq c > 0$ for some constant $c$. In our case we had $c = 1/\pi$.

Comment: I do not think $N$ is a constant.  You have shown $O\left(\frac{N}{|x|}\right)$, which is a weaker result

Comment: @Henry If $N$ is not a constant in your case then $O(N/x)$ is the best you can do, because as $N \to \infty$ the sum grows in an unbounded manner. It simply is not true that $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos(nx) = O(1/|x|)$ uniformly in $N$ for all $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: There are eventually negative terms in the sum, so the partial sum seems to oscillate, and for small $x$ seems to be very approximately  $\frac{1}{|x|}\sin(N|x|)$

Comment: @Henry whoops, you're right, in fact one can show that $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos(nx) \right| \leq |\csc(x/2)|,$$ which is stronger than what's in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A [standard identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sine_and_cosine) sometimes called *Lagrange's identity* says that our sum is equal to
$$-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sin((N+\frac{1}{2})x)}{2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}.$$